# WordPress REST API not returning all posts

Tags: posts, api, json, rest-api

I am trying to get the json data of my posts. I have tried with both v1.2.4 and v2 of the REST API plugin.

If I enter

```
http://example.com/wp-json/posts?type=magazine
```

or

```
http://example.com/wp-json/posts?type=magazine&filter[posts_per_page]=-1
```

just an empty array is returned.

If I enter

```
http://example.com/wp-json/posts?type=magazine&filter[posts_per_page]=80
```

(or any number between 1 and 80)

all data appear just fine.

Is there a limit? I need to get ALL the posts from any custom post type.

Comment: See [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-all-posts-without-pagination)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It must be that the server runs out of memory then. Do you know what could I do about that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead for pagination. It returns all the posts on my site.

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[category_name]=country&filter[posts_per_page]=-1
```

Comment: As enhancement the important part `filter[posts_per_page]=-1` without a filter, like `/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=-1`

Comment: Nope doesn't work, only ever brings back the first 10

Answer (score 0):

This article has the right answer

[How to Pull ALL Posts, Categories, or Tags in WordPress REST API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267361/how-to-pull-all-posts-categories-or-tags-in-wordpress-rest-api?rq=1)

Turns our the query parameter is `/wp-json/wp/v2/products/?per_page=xx`

Where xx is the number of posts you want.

I only needed to get twenty so not sure if there is any upper limit