# How to Pull ALL Posts, Categories, or Tags in WordPress REST API

Tags: rest-api

I have read other posts on this forum and none of which I read are solving my problem.

Whenever I do:
http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=-1

Or even:
http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=99

It still returns 10 posts. The same is happening when I try to get the Categories, or the Tags.

I have a request to pull ALL categories, tags, and posts from the REST API as a single list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts), the correct argument is `per_page`

Comment: I just tried http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[per_page]=-1 and http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[per_page]=99 with the same results. The reason I'm trying 99 is I heard they might have done away with the -1 param and limited it to 1-100. Just trying things based on what I read.

Comment: Wait! I got it. You're right.  http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100 works! Without the filter[]

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to get it beyond 100? or how I get the next 100? Maybe there's a script for this...?

Comment: No way to get around it that I know of. It's for performance reasons. Just make multiple calls using page=1, page=2, etc. It returns a total count of items found so that will tell you how many calls to make.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there'll be a filter in the posts rest API class to override this

Comment: I updated the answer with the resolution to get beyond 100 by using a loop with a page query. Just waiting for approval.

Comment: @StephenSabatini. Thanks loads `per_page=xx` works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You can only able to retrieve 100 post per page,after that use pagination as [**Wordpress wpjson post pagination**](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/).

Eg : `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&page=6`

This will fetch the 6th page and which contains 100 post ranging between 500 and 600 posts.